# How to ensure a simple power sequence of a processor without a PMIC?

Tags: power-supply, processor, pmic

I need to integrate a video processor on a PCBA (part number: AllWinner S3, [overview](https://linux-sunxi.org/S3)). It requires several power rails, and the power sequence is as follows:

- Power on:

[image]

- Power off:

[image]

(page 380/384 of the [datasheet](http://www.sochip.com.cn/s3/S3_Datasheet_V1.0.pdf))

On the [eval board](https://github.com/OLIMEX/S3-OLinuXino/blob/master/HARDWARE/S3-OLinuXino_Rev_A-release/S3-OLinuXino_Rev_A.pdf), they use a PMIC to ensure the power sequence, but I would prefer using LDOs and DC-DCs at first to be more flexible.

For the power-on, I was thinking that I could generate the rising edge of the RESET with an RC circuit. For example, if I choose R and C so that it rises in 1 s, there will be enough time for all power rails to stabilize.

But I am stuck with the power-off! I will not be able to ensure a falling edge on RESET before all the rails shut down.

Is there a simple way for me to do it? How is it generally done when there is no PMIC?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an RC circuit as you suggested and use a comparator to release the reset once the cap reaches a crrtain voltage. You can use something like an 555 circuit for this.

If you have a way of telling that a power down is about to occur (for example if you have some kind of electronic power switch instead of a mechanical one), you can simply dump the charge on the capacitor to trigger the reset immediately. But I wouldn't worry about the powerdown, even the diagram shows that the delay is supposed to be "T1 > 0", which is a strange way of saying that it *probably* won't care.